# How to show custom product attribute in Items orderd tab Magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, custom-attributes

[image: TO show a custom attribute]

I have created a custom attribute now i want to show it on in **Items Ordered** section for every product in sales -> order section.

`root\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\items.phtml` 
i found that above file shows the name Like Product, items Status and all

and the data is i think coming from below code

```
 <?php $i=0;foreach ($_items as $_item):?>
            <?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++;?>
            <tbody class="<?php echo $i%2?'even':'odd' ?>">
                <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php echo $this->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item) ?>
            </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now from here i have no idea from where the data is populated in that tabs.

```
<?php echo "custom_attribute".$_order->getData('custom_attribute'); ?>
```

even this code shows nothing.

if I `print_r($_item);` **the $_item** in

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\items\renderer\default.phtml
```

i can clearly see the `custom_attribute` but dont no how to show .

```
weee_tax_applied_row_amnt] => 0.0000
            [base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount] => 0.0000
            [weee_tax_applied_amount] => 0.0000
            [weee_tax_applied_row_amount] => 0.0000
            [weee_tax_applied] => a:0:{}
            [weee_tax_disposition] => 0.0000
            [weee_tax_row_disposition] => 0.0000
            [base_weee_tax_disposition] => 0.0000
            [base_weee_tax_row_disposition] => 0.0000
            [custom_attribute] => customattr
```

I found that 
**echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name');**  this line gave `product name and sku`
but if i do same with my attribute name as below. nothing is shown.

`echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'custom_attribute');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. So posting as answer.

1) First i created a `custom_attribute`
2) To save my `custom_attribute` in `sales_flat_order_item` i found this link https://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/

3)To check  we can  print_r($items); in this file **C:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\items\renderer\default.phtml**

4) To show the value of `custom_attribute` i used `<?php echo"<b>HSN :</b>".$_item->getcuctomAttrNameHere(); ?>`

May be this will not be a good solution , but to reach this point it took my day.

Comment: Good job Saurabh. it will be useful like us.